# How to block VS Code from opening Python setup?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time I open Visual Studio Code, the Python setup window (which opens if you want to uninstall) opens. It's really annoying. How can I fix this?[image: Annoying!!!]

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of your extensions and turning them back on slowly to see which one is triggering this?

Comment: Apart from Python, no extention is installed.

Comment: Do you know what command is triggering this? The Python extension at most runs tools you have installed and Python itself. There's no calls to any installer or anything, so I'm wondering if your Python install is somehow messed up and triggering this? Does this happen when you run Python manually? How about if you run the commands the extension does on your behalf manually (look in the Output panel for what those commands are)?